# Working with forms in Drupal 7

Tags: forms, drupal, drupal-7, client-server, submit

I have nodes keeping a picture. There is a task to provide an ability to select a type and a size of the picture in every node for further downloading to the end user device. 
To do this, I want to attach a form under every node to allow user select a type and a size they need. After user select it and put submit-button I want to process user's request, to generate the picture they need on the server side and make somehow his browser to download it. But I have no idea how to achieve this because I don't understand a mechanism of client-server exchange in Drupal 7. I know basic Form API, but it does not help me.
So, what can you advice?

**EDIT 1**

This is a source code of my module `testmodule.module`

```
<?php
function testmodule_custom_form($form, &$form_state) {
    $form=array();
    $form['image_types'] = array(
        '#type' => 'radios',
        '#title' => t('Select image type to download'),
        '#options' => array(0 => t('SVG'), 1 => t('PNG'), 2 => t('ICON')),
    );
    $form['image_sizes'] = array(
        '#type' => 'radios',
        '#title' => t('Select image size'),
        '#options' => array(0 => t('100x100'), 1 => t('200x200')),
    );
    $form['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Download'),

    );
    return $form;
}

function testmodule_custom_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    drupal_set_message('IT WORKS!!!');
}

function testmodule_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
    if($node->type === 'article') {
        $my_form = drupal_get_form('testmodule_custom_form', $node);
        $node->content['attached_form'] = array(
            '#markup' => drupal_render($my_form),
            '#weight' => 99,
        );
    }
}

function testmodule_node_presave($node) {
    $node->body[$node->language][0]['format']  = 'full_html';
    if ($node->field_image_svg[$node->language])
    {
        $file = file_load($node->field_image_svg[$node->language][0]['fid']);
        $image = new Imagick(drupal_realpath($file->uri));
        $image->setImageFormat("png");
        $destination = 'public://pngimages/'.$file->filename.'.png';
        $image->writeImage(drupal_realpath($destination)); 
        $data = file_get_contents(drupal_realpath($destination));
        $file = file_save_data($data, $destination, FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);
        $node->field_image[$node->language][0] = (array)$file;  
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to create a custom module with a form callback function.

Code sample:

```
function YOUR_MODULE_custom_form($form, &$form_state) {
    // your form controls and inputs go here
}

function YOUR_MODULE_custom_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    // your form submission handler.
    // your image resizing logic and any other logic should go here
}
```

Then in order to attach this form to nodes, create a [`hook_node_view`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7) implementation.

```
function YOUR_MODULE_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode)
{
    if($node->type === 'YOUR_CONTENT_TYPE') {
        $my_form = drupal_get_form('YOUR_MODULE_custom_form', $node);
        $node->content['your_attached_form'] = array(
            '#markup' => drupal_render($my_form),
            '#weight' => 99,
        );
    }
}
```

Hope this gets you started. I highly recommend taking your time getting familiar with Drupal form API and creating custom modules, that would make your life a lot easier :).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Muhammad, but I tried this approach and it didn't work. That is why I am wondered.
I have even copied your code in my module (with correction, of course), but it don't works again. There is not even a form in my nodes.
Have you any ideas why?
P.S. I'll add my code here in a few minutes. Look through it, please, if you have time.

Comment: I cleared a cache and now it works!!! Unbelievable... I just had to clear the cache... Damned inattention. :)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach that I generally prefer, is to use programatic blocks with defaults.

I've implements one in your code and cleaned up a few items to bring better into line with coding standards.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form().
 */
function testmodule_custom_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $form = array();
  $form['image_types'] = array(
    '#type' => 'radios',
    '#title' => t('Select image type to download'),
    '#options' => array(0 => t('SVG'), 1 => t('PNG'), 2 => t('ICON')),
  );
  $form['image_sizes'] = array(
    '#type' => 'radios',
    '#title' => t('Select image size'),
    '#options' => array(0 => t('100x100'), 1 => t('200x200')),
  );
  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Download'),

  );
  return $form;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_form_submit().
 */
function testmodule_custom_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  drupal_set_message('IT WORKS!!!');
}

/**
 * Implements hook_block_info().
 */
function testmodule_block_info() {
  $blocks = array();

  $blocks['image_download'] = array(
    'info' => t('Node - Image download'),
    'status' => 1,
    'region' => 'content',
    'visibility' => BLOCK_VISIBILITY_LISTED,
    'pages' => 'node/*',
    'cache' => DRUPAL_CACHE_PER_PAGE,
    'weight' => 1,
  );

  return $blocks;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_block_view().
 */
function testmodule_block_view($delta = '') {
  $n = menu_get_object();
  if (!$n || $n->type != 'only_particular_content_type') {
    return FALSE;
  }

  if ($delta == 'image_download') {
    return array(
      'content' => drupal_get_form('testmodule_custom_form'),
    );
  }

  return FALSE;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_node_presave().
 */
function testmodule_node_presave($node) {
  $node->body[$node->language][0]['format']  = 'full_html';
  $field_image_svg = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_image_svg');
  if (!$field_image_svg) {
    return;
  }

  $file = file_load($field_image_svg[0]['fid']);
  $image = new Imagick(drupal_realpath($file->uri));
  $image->setImageFormat("png");
  $destination = 'public://pngimages/'.$file->filename.'.png';
  $image->writeImage(drupal_realpath($destination));
  $data = file_get_contents(drupal_realpath($destination));
  $file = file_save_data($data, $destination, FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);
  $node->field_image[$node->language][0] = (array)$file;

}
```

Comment: Thank you too. But I am not familiar with processing of blocks yet. I am a beginner and blocks is one of the further topics to study.

Comment: If you get stuck with them, just drop any questions over. Take a look at:
  hook_block_info().
  hook_block_view().
  hook_block_configure().
  hook_block_save().
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21block%21block.api.php/7

Comment: Okay, I surely shall take it into consideration. And what about working with links in Drupal 7? Can you advice something? I use `drupal_goto(base_path().'/sites/default/files/tempimages/name.ext');` in my `hook_form_submit()` but it only opens an image in the same tab, and I want make it at least open in a new tab or, it would be more preferably, start download to a users drive.

Comment: I'd use $form_state['redirect'] rather than the drupal_goto. This is useful if there are any other submit handlers on the form. In your case this would be unlikely. You're looking to set the header content disposition to attachment to force the auto 'save as' implement. You can normally do this using the 'header' function in php (header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded.pdf"');) however as you are directing straight to the download you should alter the .htaccess file: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388994/forcing-a-download-using-filesmatch-in-htaccess-at-www-root